# Test Flight Internal Testing Issue

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store-connect

I am experiencing some issues with TestFlight and I am fairly new with iOS development so I am certain I must be missing something extremely small and frustrating.

We have our personal Apple IDs on our devices to test, and we sign into iTunes Connect with our work email/Apple ID (of which we were added to an organisation).

When I upload a new build and I want to get internal testers on it (take note it is only myself and another co-worker), only I get the TestFlight notification and email and **not** my co-worker. No notification, no email.

The strange part is that both of us are able to sign into iTunes Connect with our work email/Apple ID. And both of us are able to see and change details on the iTunes Connect Store.

I have tried removing him from the internal testing team and re-adding him, only for the status to show "Notified" but he does not get a notification or an email.

I have also removed TestFlight and re-installed it, and once in the application, the only available version to download is an older version (roughly a week old) and can not update the version to the latest build.

Everything was working one week ago. Any clues or advice on what to check or look out for?

Thanks to all in advance for all the help and information provided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you have verified both your work and personal accounts. Apple has weird issues with this sometimes. You will also need to verify your account details again each time you add a new email address :)

Comment: That awkward moment it boils down to something like this. Thanks lad.